# commerce stock not deducted from stock

Tags: commerce

I have a standard rule regarding commerce stock

Completing the checkout procces << minus from stock

Unfortunately my payment gateway does not require a return to the store and then
rule gets lost, does not count properly store

How to make the magazine was negative regardless of the return to the store after payment